# PHP Mysql SELECT Last month and user selected month data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve last month data and my combo-box selected month date

this is my code and this query is not working. i think the problem is in INTERVEL command. 
Please help me to use INTERVAL 1 MONTH correctly.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT manufacturer,model, SUM(replace(payment_one,',','')) as payment_one FROM table1 WHERE
 YEAR(payment_one_date) = '$YYYY'- INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND
 MONTH(payment_one_date) = '$MM'-INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND
 payment_one_bank='CB'");
```

Comment: please add sample data of table and your desired output.

Comment: payment_one = 100,000,  payment_one_date = 2016/03/30, payment_one_bank= CB like this i have different payments for different months

Comment: TRY THIS SELECT manufacturer,model, SUM(replace(payment_one,',','')) as payment_one 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
payment_one_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( 'USER_SELECTED_YEAR_MONTH_DATE', INTERVAL 1 month ) AND USER_SELECTED_YEAR_MONTH_DATE
AND payment_one_bank='CB'

Comment: still not calculating

Comment: not calculating means ?? query working or not ??

Comment: data type of payment_one_date column ?

Comment: yes query not working,  data type is varchar

Comment: @JYoThl What does that DATE_SUB means?

Comment: show me same data of payment_one_date  column

Comment: try this SELECT manufacturer,model, SUM(replace(payment_one,',','')) as payment_one 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
payment_one_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('USER_SELECTED_YEAR_MONTH_DATE','%Y,%m,%d'), INTERVAL 1 month ) AND STR_TO_DATE('USER_SELECTED_YEAR_MONTH_DATE','%Y,%m,%d')
AND payment_one_bank='CB'

Comment: @JYoThl (payment_one_date = 2016/03/30), i'm only selecting month and year from combobox when searching not full date like 2016/03/30, so i need to get sum of only selected month and previous month

Comment: try this one hopefully it will work SELECT manufacturer,model, SUM(replace(payment_one,',','')) as payment_one 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
payment_one_date 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('USER_SELECTED_YEAR_MONTH_DATE','%Y,%m,01'), INTERVAL 1 month ) AND STR_TO_DATE('USER_SELECTED_YEAR_MONTH_DATE','%Y,%m,01')
AND payment_one_bank='CB'

Comment: @JYoThl Please tell me what does that DATE_SUB means? and what shoul i use for it? This is my code 'WHERE payment_one_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('$YYYY/$MM/01','%Y,%m,‌​01'), INTERVAL 1 month ) AND STR_TO_DATE('$YYYY/$MM/01','%Y,%m,01') AND payment_one_bank='CB''

Comment: TRY THIS IN YOUR DB DIRECTLY SELECT DATE_sub( '2011-01-05', INTERVAL 1 month );  DATE_SUB GIVE THE 1 MONTH INTERVAL OF GIVEN DATE THAT MEAN PAST DATE OF GIVEN DATE

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        manufacturer,
        model,
        SUM(replace(payment_one,',','')) payment_one
    FROM table1
    WHERE (
        payment_one_date < '$YYYY-$MM-01 00:00:00' /* <-- can be incorrect for your field type */
            AND payment_one_date >= ('$YYYY-$MM-01 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ) AND payment_one_bank='CB'
```